# NGINX redirection failing

Tags: nginx

I am facing one issue on redirection.
When I click on the 1st url it's getting redirected.
When I use with passing parameter  it's not getting redirected. Could you please provide solution? I would be really thankful.

Input

https://loy-dev1.mi-devtest.sujan.com/rewards/earn-points/credit-card-rewards.mi 
Output
https://loy-dev1.mi-devtest.sujan.com/loyalty/earn/credit-card-rewards.mi

Input

https://loy-dev1.mi-devtest.sujan.com/loyalty/earn/credit-card-rewards.mi?program=america

Output
https://loy-dev1.mi-devtest.sujan.com/loyalty/earn/america-credit-card-rewards.mi

Comment: Your second input url is not the same as your first. The second one is already the redirected url

Comment: could you help me out how should i write the code for the above query